Why was the question on finding the location of the tallest buildings in a given city closed as a question "covering tasks performed by travel agent"?
The question How can I find the locations of the tallest buildings in a given city? got closed under the reason:

Questions covering tasks normally performed by travel agents such as constructing travel and tour itineraries (including scheduling and budgeting) are off-topic. They are generally too specific to your personal preference, with many variables and possibilities, and are probably not helpful to others. See also The WANTA debate.

Why? Travel agents don't do that, and the question is not too specific to the OP.
Examples of use cases:

I was looking for a swimming pool in a city that I knew was located on a high floor. Since I knew that at most only ~10 buildings were taller than this, knowing the location of the tallest buildings would have help me find it.
Earlier this year, I was trying to find the location of an AirBnB with the same strategy: I knew it was located on a high floor and couldn't see it easily on Google Maps.
Knowing the locations of the tallest buildings is also one way to orient oneself when traveling.
Sometimes I like to stay in high rises to have a nice view and/or reduce the likelihood of street noise.

So knowing the location of the tallest buildings in a given city can be useful to travelers (but not locals, since locals can just look around).
I also notice that the question was closed by a mod as the other close votes were about to expire, which further bewilders me.

Because 3 community members plus one mod (me) voted to close it. The reason is given in the box that now shows at the top of your question:
Questions covering tasks normally performed by travel agents such as constructing travel and tour itineraries (including scheduling and budgeting) are off-topic. They are generally too specific to your personal preference, with many variables and possibilities, and are probably not helpful to others. See also The WANTA debate.
We have been round this enough times, Franck, that your statement that any of this is unknown or bewildering is simply not true. This is how Stack Exchange works, and has always worked, and what you have been told multiple times on multiple sites.
You asking this sort of thing again and again on meta shows us just how much you are trying to game results, and is entirely unwelcome.

How about answering why you think it's a WANTA question? (Which is obviously the point of my meta question) Of course I know how close voting, which is why I know "Because 3 community members plus one mod (me) voted to close it." is incorrect. It's only because one mod (you) voted to close it
